# Is there a "standard" set of telephone numbers to use for testing validation code?

Tags: testing, phone-number

I have seen many different questions and discussions about validation of telephone numbers in various formats and from various countries. Can anyone point me to a comprehensive set of test data that would exercise such validation code?

I'm not looking to rehash the whole discussion on *how* to validate a phone number. That has been covered elsewhere and in sufficient detail. This is more a case of looking for the input to pass to the "black box" code that does phone number validation.

Is there a generally accepted set of data in many different formats from various countries that is considered "comprehensive"? Are there sets of country specific formats available anywhere?

Comment: It appears that there is no generally accepted set of test data that is commonly used, at least none I have found. I'm guessing most people just come up with a set of numbers they need that fit their particular application for whatever countries are affected.

Answer (score 0):

well. From my QA experience, I do not think you'll be able to find international set of telephone numbers as phone number format depends upon region, type  (simple or cell/mobile), internal or international number an so on.
So I would choose the appropriate format number  for validation in accordance with the region location.
And the second point is functional spec of the application being developed, where it is usually is described in details what type and format phone number is accepted.
The matter is one application differs from another as well as phone number formats.
Hope this somehow helps you)